# ThreadPoolExecutor.worker.run spends too much time

Tags: java, performance, profiling, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have several tasks that executed in `CachedThreadPool`. After some profiling I found that the task itself runs only 10% of time and other 90% are used by `threadpoolexecutor$worker.run` (I'm using `jvisualvm` for profiling).

And here I'm stuck. I can't figure out what the hell `threadpoolexecutor$worker.run` is doing, why it consumes so much time to do it and how to fix the problem. I need the tasks to run as fast as possible.

That's what profiler says:

```
pool-2-thread-2                                          44542 ms (100%)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run   44542 ms (100%)
        Self time                                        39598 ms (88.9%)
        MyClass.run                                       4943 ms (11.1%)
```

May be `Self time` means that thread is sleeping?

Thanks in advance.
P.S. Please sorry for the stupid, I'm not a great java programmer.

Comment: It could be a sign that the tasks are too small and more time is spent managing them than actually executing them.

Comment: @assylias But what I should do in this case? I need these tasks running simultaneously.

Comment: it's difficult to tell without having an idea of what your tasks do or seeing your code.

Comment: I'm noob. The problem was in the task's code. Java's ThreadPool works perfect. Bravo java.

Comment: @maverik Can you share your solution here?

Because I am also facing similar issue.